# Nodejs equivalent of c sscanf

Tags: node.js, matching, format-string

I need a function that behaves similar to the behavior of `sscanf`

For example, let's suppose we have a format string that looks like this (the function I'm looking for doesn't have to be exactly like this, but something similar)

```
"This is normal text that has to exactly match, but here is a ${var}"
```

And have return/modify a variable to look like

```
{'var': <whatever was there>}
```

After researching this for a while, the only things I could actually find was `scanf`, but that takes input form `stdin`, and not a *string*

I am aware that there is a regex solution for this, but I'm looking for a function that does this without the need for regex (regex is slow). However, if there is no other solution for this, I will accept a regex solution.

Comment: Have you tried to use the function `prompt()`?

Comment: @Danizavtz It seems to only accept command line input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal solution for this in most languages that have regular expressions built-in is to use regular expressions.

If you're not used to or don't like regular expressions I'm sorry. Most of the programming world have assumed that knowledge of regular expressions is mandatory.

In any case. The normal solution to this is `string.prototype.match`:

```
let text = get_string_to_scan();

let match = text.match(/This is normal text that has to exactly match, but here is a (.+)/);

if (match) { // match is null if no match is found
    // The result you want is in match[1]
    console.log('value of var is:', match[1]);
}
```

What pattern you put in your capture group (the `(..)` part) depends on what you want. The code above captures anything at all including spaces and special characters.

If you just want to capture a "word", that is, printable characters without spaces, then you can use `(\w+)`:

```
text.match(/This is normal text that has to exactly match, but here is a (\w+)/)
```

If you want to capture a word with only letters but not numbers you can use `([a-zA-Z]+)`:

```
text.match(/This is normal text that has to exactly match, but here is a ([a-zA-Z]+)/)
```

The flexibility of regular expression is why other methods of string scanning are usually not supported in languages that have had regular expression built-in since the beginning. But of course, flexibility comes with complexity.

Comment: I'm fine with regex, its just I have performance concerns

Comment: Most modern regexp libraries actually scan large strings faster than a simple scan (thus a simple scanf implementation). That's because most regexp engines have been using the Boyer-Moore algorithm to do literal search since the mid 80s or early 90s. Granted you can also implement scanf with Boyer-Moore but I don't know if they are. I do know that C++ by default do string searches slower than modern regexp engines because C++ allow you to choose Boyer-Moore as an alternative algorithm for doing string search. **Alternative**, not default.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to have the `${var}` to act as a placeholder? If so you could do it by replacing the `"` with the backtick:

```
console.log(`This is normal text that has to exactly match, but here is a ${"whatever was there"}`)
```

Comment: im not sure if you understand what `sscanf` actually does. It takes a string and another string and it parses it according to the format string. I want something similar to that, but instead the reverse of creating this string

Comment: Oh ok sorry guess i interpreted your question wrongly.